# How to read .cwl file in R/Python?

Tags: python, r, common-workflow-language

I try to write a script in R, which requires to modify a `.cwl` file. Take a minimal example of `test.cwl` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env cwl-runner

cwlVersion: v1.0
class: Workflow

requirements:
  - class: StepInputExpressionRequirement

inputs:
  - id: submissionId
    type: int

outputs: []
```

Ideally, I want to read this `test.cwl` and modify the `inputs$id`. Finally, write out to an updated `new_test.cwl` file. However, I can't find a way to read this `test.cwl` file in R? I have tried [tidycwl](https://github.com/sbg/tidycwl), but it can only read files with `ymal` or `json` extension.

If any packages from python will do the trick, I would also be happy to use it with `reticulate`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @nuno-carvalho's answer, I added ruamel.yaml to fix indent for arrays:

```
pip install ruamel.yaml
```

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
with open("test.cwl", 'r') as cwl_file:
    cwl_dict = yaml.load(cwl_file)

with open("test-new.cwl", 'w') as cwl_file:
    cwl_dict["inputs"] = [{"id": 2, "type": "ABC"}]
    yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
    yaml.dump(cwl_dict, cwl_file)
```

Output:

```
cwlVersion: v1.0
class: Workflow
requirements:
  - class: StepInputExpressionRequirement
inputs:
  - id: 2
    type: ABC
outputs: []
```

I am not good at python, please feel to suggest

Answer (score 1):

Install PyYAML:

`pip install PyYAML==6.0`

Run this script:

```
import yaml
# Read file
with open("test.cwl", 'r') as cwl_file:  
    cwl_dict = yaml.safe_load(cwl_file)

# Write file
with open("test-new.cwl", 'w') as cwl_file:
    cwl_dict["inputs"] = [{"id" : 2, "type": "ABC"}]
    yaml.dump(cwl_dict, cwl_file)
```

**Later Edit suggested by**  [WenliL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16729348/wenlil) **to fix identation**

```
pip install ruamel.yaml
```

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
with open("test.cwl", 'r') as cwl_file:
    cwl_dict = yaml.load(cwl_file)

with open("test-new.cwl", 'w') as cwl_file:
    cwl_dict["inputs"] = [{"id": 2, "type": "ABC"}]
    yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
    yaml.dump(cwl_dict, cwl_file)
```

Output:

```
cwlVersion: v1.0
class: Workflow
requirements:
  - class: StepInputExpressionRequirement
inputs:
  - id: 2
    type: ABC
outputs: []
```

Comment: How to fix the indent?  The  `test-new.cwl` indent is not correct.

Comment: This approach generates a valid yaml file. Taking a look at this documentation(link below) I see that cwl format follows yaml rules. Therefore, It should be a valid cwl file. Do you agree? https://www.commonwl.org/user_guide/yaml/

Comment: the output of this approach does not have the indent for arrays. If you check the link you share, there are indents before array elements, before each "-". Is there a way to add indent for that?

Comment: I have found a way to fix indent using ruamel.yaml. I post it to the answer. I am not good at python. Please feel to modify it and edit your answer. So that I can accept your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(cwl_file_path, 'r') as cwl_file:  
    cwl_dict = yaml.safe_load(cwl_file)
```

More information for yaml:

https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation

Comment: What is `yaml`? This looks like Python and that isn't part of the standard library. Please read [answer].